# jQuery - combine statements

Tags: jquery

Could i trouble someone to help me combine these statements...everytime i do i get a script error, but am unable to debug what is exactly wrong...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
      $('.slideshow').after('<div id="mininav"
  class="mininav">').cycle({
          fx:     'fade',
          speed:  'fast',
          timeout: 5500,    pause: 1,
          pager:  '#mininav',
          before: function() { if (window.console)
  console.log(this.src); }
      });


  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {

   $('.slideshow').hover(function() {   
          $('#mininav-pause').show();   }, 
            function() {        $('#mininav-pause').hide();     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Care to post the error you are getting or you don't find this as an important part of your question?

Comment: Can you recreate your issue on jsfiddle.net so we can take a better look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
      $('.slideshow')
      .after('<div id="mininav" class="mininav">')
      .cycle({
          fx:     'fade',
          speed:  'fast',
          timeout: 5500,
          pause: 1,
          pager:  '#mininav',
          before: function() { if (window.console) console.log(this.src); }
      })
      .hover(function() { $('#mininav-pause').show(); }, 
             function() { $('#mininav-pause').hide(); });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div should have the closing slash and you can combine hover functions.

```
<script> 
  $(function() {
      $('.slideshow')
          .after('<div id="mininav" class="mininav" />')
          .cycle({
              fx:     'fade',
              speed:  'fast',
              timeout: 5500,    pause: 1,
              pager:  '#mininav',
              before: function() { 
                  if (window.console)
                  { console.log(this.src); }
              }
          })
          .hover(function() {   
              $('#mininav-pause').toggle();
          });
  });
</script>
```